# Not able to prepare my MERN app for deployment using separate server and client deployments

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, render, mern

This is my first deployment of a MERN app and I am having problems getting the frontend to communicate with my backend! I have read the other questions on Stack Overflow but nothing has worked so far.

I have deployed the MERN stack app on Render.
Front end React App = static site
https://bookingappclient.onrender.com/

Back end Node/Mongo server = web service
https://bookingappapi-5wfa.onrender.com/

Both work separately and I am able to successfully query my server using POSTMAN.
However all requests by the frontend itself to the server return 404.

I have been working on this for a couple of days and I am stuck!!

**Booking App Api**

[BookingAppApi Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3E31.png)

settings within Render

buildcommand: npm ci
startcommand: node index.js

Index.js

```
//Install dotenv package
//then we can access our connection details via process.env from the .env file

import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.js";
import usersRoute from "./routes/users.js";
import hotelsRoute from "./routes/hotels.js";
import roomsRoute from "./routes/rooms.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import path from 'path';

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO);
        console.log("Connected to mongoDB.");
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

;

mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
    console.log("mongoDB disconnected!");
});

//middlewares
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['https://bookingappclient.onrender.com/']
})) app.use(cookieParser()) // we use this middlware because by defauly you cannot send json unless you use this middleware

app.use(express.json());


app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", usersRoute);
app.use("/api/hotels", hotelsRoute);
app.use("/api/rooms", roomsRoute);

const __dirname = path.resolve();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

    //set static folder

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))

    //any route that is not one of the listed api routes above, will be redircted to index.html

    app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')))

} else {

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Api is running')
    })
}



app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const errorStatus = err.status || 500;
    const errorMessage = err.message || "Something went wrong!";

    return res.status(errorStatus).json({
        success: false,
        status: errorStatus,
        message: errorMessage,
        stack: err.stack,
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8800, () => {
    connect();
    console.log("Connected to backend.");
});
```

.env

```
NODE_ENV = production
```

package.json

```
    "name": "bookingapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon index.js"
    }
    ,
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.3.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
    }
}
```

**Booking App Client **

[Booking App Client Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wHEN.png)

package.json

```
    "name": "booking",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
        "react": "^18.0.0",
        "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ],
        ,
        "proxy": "https://bookingappapi-5wfa.onrender.com/api"
    }
}
```

settings within Render

publish directory: build Build Command:  `npm ci && npm run build`

**Errors **

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqMuq.png)

I have tried using the Redirects and Rewrites settings directly within Render but this produces a different error with too many redirects.